# zsh create a command line within a script but do not execute it

Tags: zsh

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a zsh script that will write a command to the prompt but NOT execute it, i.e. leave it there for me to edit and then execute when I'm ready. I can do something  like this with keybindings by leaving off the final '\C-m'. eg:

```
bindkey -s "\e[1;3C" "howdy!"
```

... I press Alt+RightArrow and the text "howdy!" is printed at the prompt and just left there.

I can also do something like what I want by writing my command to the history file and then recalling it with the up arrow. I've tried 'echo -n sometext' but it doesn't work.

Can I write a script that would exit leaving (say) " howdy! " on the command line?  In actual fact I want the script to build up a complex command based on several things, but I want the script to leave it on the CLI for final editing, so automatic execution must be prevented.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out the answer is simple:

```
print -z $string-to-print
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a zsh function and not an external script, you can write a zle (short for *zsh line editor*) widget and bind it to some key.

```
# define to function to use
hello () {
 BUFFER=hello
 zle end-of-line
}
# create a zle widget, which will invoke the function.
zle -N hello
# bindkey Alt-a to that widget
bindkey "\ea" hello
```

You can learn more from [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell, Chapter 4](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html).

Comment: zle: function definition file not found
zle: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active

Comment: lilydjwg, Thanks. There's stuff to chew on in your post, and it binds the key exactly as you suggest. But it still does not help me create a script that will leave something on the command line when it exits. I thought the 'hello' function above looked promising and tried to fool around with that but I can't get it to run by itself from the command line. With 'autoload -U zle' in my .zshrc I get: zle: function definition file not found ... with my .zshrc unmodified I get: zle: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active I know I have a lot of reading to do :(

Comment: @rayandrews: How did you call the zle command that causes this error?

Comment: I just typed 'hello' 'zle hello' and a few other efforts on CLI and got those errors. But I know absolutely nothing about this 'zle', I was just hoping for the best.  Anyway, it seems there's a dead simple solution to my problem: "print -z $the-command-string" does exactly what I want.